# Construction of the five planar lattices

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometry

I don't understand a passage my text employs to derive the five planar lattices.

[image]

A planar lattice $L$, is generated by linear combinations of two independet vectors $m\mathbf{a} + n\mathbf{b}$,  with $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Where $\mathbf{a}$ is taken as the minimum lenght vector in $L$ and $\mathbf{b}$ as the non-parallel to $\mathbf{a}$ minimum lenght vector in $L$.

To derive the planar lattice the text I'm reading uses this construction:

> Replace if necessary $\mathbf{b}$ by $-\mathbf{b}$, to ensure that
>
> $|a − b| ≤ |a + b| \tag 1$
>
> With this assumption the different lattices are defined as
> follows
>
> 1. Oblique: |***a***| < |***b***| <
>    |***a*** −***b***| < |***a*** +
>    ***b***|
> 2. Rectangular: |***a***| < |***b***| <
>    |***a*** − ***b***| = |***a*** +
>    ***b***|
> 3. Centred Rectangular: |***a***| < |***b***|
>    = |***a*** − ***b***| < |***a*** + ***b***|
> 4. Square: |***a***| = |***b***| <
>    |***a*** − ***b***| = |***a*** +
>    ***b***|
> 5. Hexagonal: |***a***| = |***b***| =
>    |***a*** − ***b***| < |***a*** +
>    ***b***|

I don't understand why inequality $(1)$ must be satisfied;
|***a***| ≤ |***b***| derives by the choice of the two vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ but I don't understand why |***a*** −***b***| ≤ |***a*** + ***b***| must hold (and when it doesn't is necessary to replace $\mathbf{b}$ by $-\mathbf{b}$).

Comment: The author tries to classify all all planar lattices. Check if  this is the case, that means, if ever type of lattice belongs to one of these 5 classes. This should be the case. Then skip the condition $(1)$ and try to define the 5 classifications again, so that you get the same 5 classes.

Comment: What type of lattice is defined by  (4,7) and (5,9)?

Comment: Which text are you reading?

Comment: Armstrong_M. A._Groups and symmetry-Springer (1988);
(4,7) and (5,9) is a case in which you should replace b by -b. After calculating the modules I've obtained a rectangular one.

Comment: 1. (4,7) and (5,9) can be reduced to (1,0) and (0,1). vector a is the minimum, e.g. (0,1) or (1,0), b is not only non parallel, it is the smallest non parallel vector. So we have not case 2.Rectangular but case 4.Square. And this is a case where we have to change from b to -b, because there is no differenct if a and b are rectangular. Different pairs of vectors can define the same lattice. To find out if two lattices are the same or to find out, which type the lattice has, we transform the basis to some kind of standard basis: a is the smalllest, b is the smallest in a different direction.

Comment: 2. a ist not uniquely defined, because -a has the same length. In case of a square lattice we have even the perpendicualr vector to a that has the same length. If we have choosen a, we can choose b uniquely if we take care that |a-b|<|a+b|.